# Error loading BuildConfig (Grails 2.1.0)

Tags: grails

I've been racking my brain for hours trying to figure this out.  Whenever I try to perform any kind of action to my newly created Grails project (with a fresh Grails install), I get this error message:

```
Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: ivy pattern must be absolute: 
${HOME}/.m2/alpha/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-
[classifier]).pom (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I can deduce that there's a problem with my installation, but its a fresh install as I said so I'm not sure what could have caused this problem already.

I'm running Win7.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0.RC1'
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your BuildConfig.

Comment: @Gregg I've updated the post with my BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved for now.

It was a Maven problem, which I didn't consider initially.  For some reason, the localRepository tag in /Users/USERNAME/.mp2/settings.xml couldn't resolve the path to HOME, so replacing ${HOME} with the C:/Users/USERNAME did the trick.  Strange but it works for now.  If anyone has a better solution let me know!

Comment: Hi Ben, I think your conclusion is wrong. It is still Ivy problem, as you don't run Apache Maven build. Ordinary Maven will be able to resolve the parameterized ${user.home}, while Grails is actually using Ivy, trying to resolve but failed.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was a little different:

(1) Create a variable that points to your .m2 repository location:

```
def localMavenRepo = "file://" + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
```

(2) Create a repository entry:

```
repositories { 
    ... 
    mavenRepo name: 'Local', root: localMavenRepo 
}
```

Comment: It worked like that. I commented-out these lines: mavenLocal(); mavenCentral() and added the local mavenRepo declaration. Alternatively (for quick testing) someone could just comment-out the mavenLocal(), and update remotely (not recommended to keep it like this).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem.
I think it's not Maven problem, it's Apache Ivy's problem.

I think Apache Maven 2/3 works well, it's just that Apache Ivy didn't pick the correct Maven folder. The Apache Ivy didn't expand the ${user.home} as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting my `M2_REPO` environment variable to an absolute path. On linux:

```
export M2_HOME=/home/chris/.m2/repository/
```

On windows you can set environment variables in the System Properties dialog (shortcut to System Properties is *WindowsKey*+*PauseKey*). Go to *System Properties* -> *Advanced* -> *Environment Variables*.